# .htaccess for redirecting rss feed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect each URL ending with /feed to mysite.com/rss

My old subscribers have links such as mysite.com/something/feed or mysite.com/otherthing/something/feed and I want to redirect them all to mysite.com/rss now.

How would I go about generating the redirect in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite, whichever one is more suitable with whatever other rules/settings you have. Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /feed$ /rss
```

or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /?feed$ /rss [L,R=301]
```